# HTACCESS rule to encode get params (%3f)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

title pretty much surmises what I am trying to achieve,
this is a server only thing, no other intermediate languages but
Apache. The purpose of this is to render downloaded webpages that
have GET requests appended to them, and treat them like independent
web pages.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/bar/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I know that this is possible as I did it by accident yesterday, but forgot to take notes on how it was accomplished.

Comment: By "turn a request from", you mean redirect the browser?

Comment: I specifically had ment "turning a request from the server for an asset" but a 301/302 would be fine if it accomplishes the same goal, updated my verbiage so hopefully it makes more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule for turning `/index.asp%3fid=12345` internally into `/index.asp?id=12345`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]*)\?([^=]+=[^\s&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1\%3f%2? [L,NE,R]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.(?:php|asp))[^=]+=(.+)$ /$1?id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Two things, one the index is dynamic, I never know what file I will have to change this needs to operate on ALL FILES, so it will need to account for everything. This is also true with the query string, I never know what the parameter is. Plus one for a good looking answer though.

Comment: Ok I made index part generic but can you post some more examples in your questions as per your comment so that I can understand and modify the code accordingly.

Comment: I just realized, you are doing the REVERSE of what I was asking, I'm trying to turn ? into %3f !!!